# How to give a company my app so they can publish it on the appStore without giving my code?

Tags: ios, deployment, app-store

we got a contract to make an app for a big company. We produced the app in xcode, but we don't have access to their developer account from apple, so we can't publish it to the store under their account.

Is it possible for me to give them the app compiled, so they can publish it to the store as if it where their app? If yes, how can I compile the app so that it will be compatible/signed and they can publish it without trouble?

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to compile it and sign it from XCode using the distribution profile of the account it's going to be uploaded to, it's a security measure. They'll have to give you the distribution profile at least.

Comment: ok thanks, that can be easily done. just to confirm: they don't need to create an account for me?

Comment: I'm not sure how easy is to import a distribution profile, they may need to do an account for you as part of the team, I did that is the past